# How would I create one data set from a table that contains two identical values in the first column but different data in the remaining columns Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have produced a dataset where some of the data has two identical memberkeys but different contract values, while other memberkeys only appear once. I need to merge those memberkeys that have two rows into one distinct memberkey row containing all the data from both rows while leaving the single row memberkey as is.

Current

| MemberKey | SubscriberKey | VALUEONE | VALUETWO | VALUETHREE | VALUEFOUR | VALUEFIVE | VALUESIX | VALUESEVEN | VALUEEIGHT | VALUENINE | VALUETEN | VALUEELEVEN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2235 |  |  |  | H4931 | MA84100303 | ENGLISH | ACOC |  |  | 5TX4VV3TD79 | 13 | 1 |
| 2235 | 2235 | A84100303 | b |  |  | ENGLISH |  | AUCOC | A84100303 |  |  |  |
| 4375 |  |  |  | H4931 | MA48450239 | SPANISH | APIM |  |  | 9QP3K96WK88 | 14 | 1 |
| 4375 | 4375 | A48450239 |  |  |  | SPANISH |  | AUPIM | A48450239 |  |  |  |
| 375 | 375 |  |  | H4931 | MA08111511 | ENGLISH | AMAR |  |  | 8B06P95CG54 |  |  |

Desired

| MemberKey | SubscriberKey | VALUEONE | VALUETWO | VALUETHREE | VALUEFOUR | VALUEFIVE | VALUESIX | VALUESEVEN | VALUEEIGHT | VALUENINE | VALUETEN | VALUEELEVEN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2235 | 2235 | A84100303 | b | H4931 | MA84100303 | ENGLISH | ACOC | AUCOC | A84100303 | 5TX4VV3TD79 | 13 | 1 |
| 4375 | 4375 | A48450239 |  | H4931 | MA48450239 | SPANISH | APIM | AUPIM | A48450239 | 9QP3K96WK88 | 14 | 1 |
| 375 | 375 |  |  | H4931 | MA08111511 | ENGLISH | AMAR |  |  | 8B06P95CG54 |  |  |

I've tried several approaches (ctes, temp tables, convoluted joins etc) without success.
Thanks

Comment: Could you post an example that shows what you have and what you'd want to get?

Comment: Please post your sample data and expected result. It seems you need a LISTAGG.

Comment: Where a single key has multiple rows, can any indivudal column ever have more than one distinct value?  *(For example, could `VALUEFIVE` ever have both `'ENGLISH'` **and** `'SPANISH'` for the same MemberKey?)*  Also, do you want to modify a table, or just write a `SELECT`?

Comment: The columns would not have two different values for the two rows with the same memberkey

Comment: I am open to either modifying the underlying table to get the results I am looking for or writing a select that would give me the output I am looking for. Not sure which would be easier

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a table and then update this new table with your old table using by joining on the memberkey?

```
update new_table a
    set a.valueone = (select max(x.valueone)
                        from old_table x
                        where a.memberkey = x.memberkey);
commit;
```

This would work as long as for the same memberkey you do not have a different value for the same column.

Comment: Not sure this would work across multiple columns that needed to be updated

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

MERGE INTO MEMBERS m2
USING MEMBERS_GTT m1 ON ( m1.MemberKey = m2.MemberKey )
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
UPDATE SET m2.SUBSCRIBERKEY = COALESCE(m1.SUBSCRIBERKEY,m2.SUBSCRIBERKEY)

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
 THEN 
  INSERT  ( MemberKey , 
 SUBSCRIBERKEY 
  ) 
   VALUES (  m1.MemberKey , 
       m1.SUBSCRIBERKEY 
   )
```